# Proving a function is continuous and periodic

Tags: trigonometry, summation, fourier-series, periodic-functions

Suppose we are given a function 
$$g\left ( x \right )= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left ( nx \right )}{10^{n}\sin \left ( x \right )},x\neq k\pi , k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
and 
$$g\left ( k\pi \right )=\lim _{x\rightarrow k\pi}g\left ( x \right )$$
I found that $\lim _{x\rightarrow k\pi}g\left ( x \right )= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{n}}$ for both odd and even $k$. However, I am still unsure how to proceed from here. What does continuity even mean for functions like this? If I wanted to take the derivative of this function, surely I must prove first that it converges and then I would apply differentiation term by term. 
Proving periodicity for one term would be easy enough if it weren't for the $10^{n}$ term in the denominator. How to deal with it? 
*EDIT*: How to find the Fourier series of this function( by first proving that Dirichlet's conditions are met)

Comment: All of the terms are periodic with period $2\pi$. So the pointwise convergence of the series implies that $g$ has period $2\pi$. Every term of the series is continuous [provided we interpret the removable singularities at $k\pi$ of each term removed], so uniform convergence implies continuity of $g$. Since uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, you should try to prove uniform convergence. For differentiability, you should try to prove uniform convergence of the termwise differentiated series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a basic precalculus fact that for arbitrary complex $z$ with $|z|<1$ one has
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k={1\over 1-z}\ .$$
Furthermore, by Euler's equation, for arbitrary real $x$ we may write $\sin x={\rm Im}\>e^{ix}$ . Putting these two together we obtain
$$\eqalign{\sum_{n=1}^\infty{\sin (nx)\over 10^n}&={\rm Im}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left({e^{ix}\over10}\right)^n={\rm Im}{e^{ix}/10\over 1-e^{ix}/10}\cr &={\rm Im}{e^{ix}(10-e^{-ix})\over (10-e^{ix})(10-e^{-ix})}={10\sin x\over101-20\cos x}\ .\cr}$$
It follows that
$$g(x)={10\over 101-20\cos x}\qquad(x\in{\mathbb R}\setminus \pi{\mathbb Z})\ .\tag{1}$$
It follows that the apparent singularities at integer $x$ are removable, so that $g$ has a natural $C^\infty$ extension to all of ${\mathbb R}$, and this extension is $2\pi$-periodic. Note that the initially given expression for $g$ is *not* its Fourier series. In order to obtain the latter one would have to compute the integrals $$a_k:={1\over\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}g(x)\>\cos(kx)\>dx\ ,$$ using the expression $(1)$ for $g$. The resulting expressions for the $a_k$ will not be simple.

Comment: Is that a well known value you got  for the sum in the first paragraph?

Comment: It is based on the sum of an infinite geometric series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac1{1-r}$ for $|r|<1$

Comment: To be quite honest, this is my weak spot. Do you have some sources to learn from about geometric series. If I'm not mistaken these are complex series, which are quite different from real ones.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure that I arrive to the same result $$g(k\pi)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{10^{n}}=\frac{1}{9}$$

Using complex representation of $\sin(x)$, what I got is that $$g\left ( x \right )= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin \left ( nx \right )}{10^{n}\sin \left ( x \right )}=-\frac{10 e^{i x}}{\left(-10+e^{i x}\right) \left(-1+10 e^{i x}\right)}$$ So, $g\big(2k\pi\big)=\frac{10}{81}$, $g\big((2k+1)\pi\big)=\frac{10}{121}$.

Comment: How did you get there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

You should first examine the series

$\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (nx)}}{{{{10}^n}}}} $ 
and check that this is a continuous function.

Looking at the form of the series, think of geometric series

$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{z^n}}}{{{{10}^n}}}} $ .
Then by the theory of power series, $f(z)$ converges in a disk of radius 10.
Therefore, it converges uniformly to a differentiable function in the closed unit disk.

Now $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (nx)}}{{{{10}^n}}}} $ is just the imaginary part of $f(z)$, i.e., $Im(f(z))$ on the unit circle.
Now

$f(z) = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{{z^n}}}{{{{10}^n}}}}  = \frac{1}{{1 - {\textstyle{z \over {10}}}}} - 1 = \frac{z}{{10 - z}}$  and so

$f({e^{ix}}) = \frac{{{e^{ix}}}}{{10 - {e^{ix}}}} = \frac{{10\cos (x) - 1}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}} + i\frac{{10\sin (x)}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}}$.

Thus $\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\sin (nx)}}{{{{10}^n}}}} $ 
converges uniformly to the differentiable function

$\frac{{10\sin (x)}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}}$ on the whole real line.

Therefore, for $x$ not a multiple of $\pi $,

$g(x) = \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}}$ .

Since 
$\mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to k\pi } g(x) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to k\pi } \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}} = \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos (k\pi )}}$ ,
we may consider $g(x)$ as given by 
$g(x) = \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}}$ by giving it the value of its limit at all multiple of $\pi $.
Thus, taking the limit or not,
$g(2k\pi ) = \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos (2k\pi )}} = \frac{{10}}{{81}}$ and 
$g((2k + 1)\pi ) = \frac{{10}}{{101 - 20\cos ((2k + 1)\pi )}} = \frac{{10}}{{121}}$ .

You can now use $g(x)$ in this form to find its Fourier series.

g is an even function of period $ 2 \pi $.  So it has a cosine Fourier series with coefficients $ {a_n}$ given by

${a_n} = \frac{1}{\pi }\int_0^{2\pi } {\frac{{10\cos (nx)}}{{101 - 20\cos (x)}}dx}  = \frac{2}{{99 \times {{10}^{n - 1}}}}$ , for $ n = 0, 1 ,2, ... $

You can use complex contour integration to evaluate the integrals.

Answer (score 0):

First check that function converge uniformly. It sure does, on this union: $x \in I = \bigcup_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} (\pi k,\, \pi (k+1))$ because:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^n} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{10^n} \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{|\sin(x)|} \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n}{10^n}
$$
Now in singular points $\lim_{x \to k \pi} \; g(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{10^n} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)}$ . The interesting part here is just $\frac{\sin(n x)}{\sin(x)}$. Here is pretty handy formula that $\sin(x + y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$. You can now rewrite the limit:
$$
\lim_{x \to k \pi} 10^{-n} \frac{\sin(xn)}{\sin(x)} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} 10^{-n}\frac{\sin(n\varepsilon + n k \pi)}{\sin(\varepsilon + k \pi)} = \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0} 10^{-n}\frac{\sin(n\varepsilon)(-1)^{nk} + 0}{\sin(\varepsilon) (-1)^k + 0} =  10^{-n} (-1)^{-n} n
$$
Now you can see that it is continous on whole $\mathbb{R}$.
Continuity: $\lim_{x \to x'} g(x) = g(x')$. 10^{-n} does not affect periodicity of this function. To prove periodicity, you just have to prove that there exists such $\exists T \in \mathbb{R}\forall t \in \mathbb{R}: g(t + T) = g(t)$. There is such $T$ and it is equal to $2 \pi$. Just use that trick that is above in section where I tried to estimate limit in $k \pi$. If you look at the function you can see that the function is even. So you dont have to calculate odd coeficients in fourier series.
$$
a_m = \frac{2}{2 \pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} 10^{-n} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)} \cos\bigg(m \frac{2 \pi x}{2\pi}\bigg) \mathrm{d}x = \frac{2}{\pi} \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \int_{0}^{\pi}  10^{-n} \frac{\sin(nx)}{\sin(x)} \cos(m x) \mathrm{d}x
$$